# Is it legal under international law to distribute passports among citizens of another country?

Tags: international

In the last few days Russian president Vladimir Putin has been publicly considering offering [fast-track passports to Ukrainian citizens](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-ukraine-crisis-russia-putin/putin-says-russia-may-offer-fast-tracked-passports-to-all-ukrainians-idUSKCN1S307U). Some sources quote concerns that the Russian government could eventually use these newly acquired citizens as a reason for military intervention. Since this problem may have occured before in history, my question is as follows:

Is it legal unter international law to distribute passports among citizens of another country?

If it is not, are there restrictions as to who is eligible for passports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any country can certainly decide who it should grant citizenship status to. There is no international rule that I know of requiring that the recipient be currently a resident of the country granting citizenship. Any country may issue passports to its citizens.

Comment: China's reaction to the United Kingdom's granting favorable immigration treatment to people from Hong Kong is a counterexample.

Comment: @phoog That isn't a rule of international law, that is an attempt at international pressure. Countries have always felt free to pressure others to do things, if they had power enough.

Comment: As I understand it, the UK undertook a treaty obligation not to give those people British citizenship or any other status conferring a right of abode in the UK.  If that understanding is correct then the UK is not, as a matter of international law,  free to decide who it should grant citizenship to.

Comment: Having looked into it a bit, I haven't found any explicit written undertaking to that effect, in which case it is indeed more of a case of diplomatic pressure than of international law.  But I only scanned the Sino-British Joint Declaration without researching any of the background, so it was a fairly superficial investigation.